# RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number when Deploying Pyspark model to Azure Container Instance

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

I am trying to deploy a PySpark model trained in Azure Databricks with MLflow to an ACI in Azure Machine Learning.

I am following the steps in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-mlflow-models#example-notebooks

but I get this error:

```
SPARK_HOME not set. Skipping PySpark Initialization.
Initializing logger
2022-02-21 09:29:30,269 | root | INFO | Starting up app insights client
logging socket was found. logging is available.
logging socket was found. logging is available.
2022-02-21 09:29:30,270 | root | INFO | Starting up request id generator
2022-02-21 09:29:30,270 | root | INFO | Starting up app insight hooks
2022-02-21 09:29:30,270 | root | INFO | Invoking user's init function
JAVA_HOME is not set
2022-02-21 09:29:31,267 | root | ERROR | User's init function failed
2022-02-21 09:29:31,268 | root | ERROR | Encountered Exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/azureml-server/aml_blueprint.py", line 191, in register
    main.init()
  File "/var/azureml-app/execution_script.py", line 15, in init
    model = load_model(model_path)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py", line 667, in load_model
    model_impl = importlib.import_module(conf[MAIN])._load_pyfunc(data_path)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/spark.py", line 703, in _load_pyfunc
    pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config("spark.python.worker.reuse", True)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 144, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 339, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_5d25bdfadca034daea176336163db1e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

My code looks like this:

```
from mlflow.deployments import get_deploy_client

# set the tracking uri as the deployment client
client = get_deploy_client(mlflow.get_tracking_uri())

# set the model path 
model_path = "k_means_model"

    # define the model path and the name is the service name
    # the model gets registered automatically and a name is autogenerated using the "name" parameter below 
    client.create_deployment(model_uri='runs:/{}/{}'.format(run_id, model_path), name = 'k-means-model-ml-flow')
```

While my model settings are:

```
artifact_path: k_means_model
databricks_runtime: 10.3.x-cpu-ml-scala2.12
flavors:
  python_function:
    data: sparkml
    env: conda.yaml
    loader_module: mlflow.spark
    python_version: 3.8.10
  spark:
    model_data: sparkml
    pyspark_version: 3.2.1
model_uuid: 76ba9dfb01e1428ab8145a161ec3cf32
run_id: c0090fa9-b382-45b8-be08-d05e16f3cd62
utc_time_created: '2022-02-21 08:47:34.967167'
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: show your code and settings

Comment: @AlexOtt Added my code and settings!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues given in logs.

> Error – SPARK_HOME not set.

> Error – JAVA_HOME is not set.

Make sure SPARK and JAVA settings are configured.

Try to run code with previous versions of SPARK.

If problems still persist, you can raise [ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) here.